# Twitter API through POSTMAN

Tags: twitter, oauth-2.0

I was trying to hit Twitter API to retrieve data from POSTMAN but I am stuck at an error.

I have created a project in Twitter and then created an app which is associated with the twitter project. Retrieved the Key, Secret and Bearer Token. I hit the below endpoint with Bearer token and got the error.

**endpoint** : https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets

Error: When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal.

Then I hot the same endpoint using OAuth 1.0 with Consumer Key, Consumer Secret, Access Token and Access Secret and getting the below error